# How to make SSRS report compitible with all browser?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have created one SSRS report in Microsoft visual studio 2005 with reporting services. it runs fine in IE and displayed properly. but my requirement is to make it compatible with all the browser. It doesn't displayed properly in Non-IE browsers like Chrome, Safari and Mozilla. Its Dimensions get Shrink in these Non-IE-Browsers. So is there any way can i make this report browser-compatible? Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you displaying the report?

Comment: You will have to edit CSS file from report manager.

Comment: I m displaying reports created using BIDS in report server as well as report manager. but yes we report server is used by clients so in that reports should be contemptible in all the browsers.

Comment: Ya i got your point but what kind of changes i need to do in css file of report manager and after doing it will work or not?